# How to unload content from loaded div by AJAX

Tags: html, ajax

I loaded some content in a DIV with AJAX. Then, i loaded different content from content that i loaded before. But it seems, previous loaded content is not gone, cuz there is a conflict between same named elements.

Is there a way to clean up that previously loaded content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always set a blank value to the div if you no longer need the content.

```
 $('#yourdiv').html("");
 //reload with AJAX
```

Comment: ok but how can i use AJAXUPLOAD plugin in the new loaded content, even though i didnt include it to page ??

Comment: @Ahmet. Sorry my answer actually assumed you were using the jQuery library for JavaScript. If you are not you need to look at the answer given by @Gregoire.

Answer (score 2):

```
yourDiv.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: oh...I actually assumed jQuery when I saw the question. Hmm.